# Laravel Facades - Passing parameter to __construct()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, facade

If I am creating a Facade, and I want to pass parameters before it becomes instantiated, what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facade's underlying service is resolved through the IoC container, so all you have to do is bind it correctly.

Create a [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/providers#introduction), and pass in whatever you want:

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class FooServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('foo', function()
        {
            return new Foo('pass whatever you want');
        });
    }
}
```

Don't forget to load the service provider in your app's config array.

Then use that bound key in your facade:

```
class Bar extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'foo'; }

}
```

Comment: @michabbb - what do you call `'pass whatever you want'`, if not a parameter?

Comment: `$this->app->bind('foo',function ($app){
    return new Foo($app);
});`